# Finding the largest k-clique, k-club, k-plex, and k-core of a small undirected graph.

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

I'm only able to find simple definitions of these k values, and I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the questions.

[image: Image of Undirected Graph]

a) Find a k-clique with the largest possible value of

b) Find a -club with the largest possible value of

c) Find a -core with the largest possible value of

d) Find a -plex with the largest possible value of

Comment: Do you suppose you could tell us the definitions, or at least link to them? Or do we have to look them up ourselves before we can help you with your question?

Comment: A clique is a set of vertices joined each to each by edges; obviously the biggest clique in your graph is the 4-clique consisting of the four vertices labeled 1, 2, 3, and 4. "Core" sounds vaguely familiar but I wouldn't want to guess; I'm sure I never heard of a club or a plex.

Comment: I've figured out answers to c and d but there isn't much on k-clubs.. let alone any example problems that are easy found.

Comment: What are the definitions of club, core, and plex?